# How to check if python user input is a valid character

Tags: python, input, user-input

Im trying to get user input for my script. And the User input can only be 2 characters a dot(".") or a dash("-") I got it to check if its either of the characters the first time and it works. But If you for example put in a "b" itll then say invalid character and retry the input. Only problem is that if u put in a invalid character twice in a row it somehow thinks its a valid character a valid Character being a "." or "-" only.

Current Code:

```
character_a = input('Enter First Dot or Dash (. / -): ')

if not character_a == ".":
    if not character_a == "-":
        print('Invalid Character.. Try Again')
        character_a = input('Enter First Dot or Dash (. / -): ')
        

if character_a == "." or "-":
    print('Valid Character')
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). This includes text from your terminal.

Comment: `if character_a == "." or "-"` is saying `if (character_a == ".") or if ("-")`, so will always be true.

Comment: How Can I fix that?